# image won't show on inflated ImageView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-imageview, android-inflate

I'm trying to inflate a photo that i took via camera on on ImageView but get NPE.

```
 public void onDescriptionClick(){

      RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.camap);
      View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pic_check, mainLayout, false);
      RelativeLayout inflatedLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.inflated);
      ImageView iv= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgv);
      mainLayout.addView(inflatedLayout);

      inflatedLayout.addView(iv);

      iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);//here i get NPE
}
```

help will be appreciated

Comment: Your bitmap is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the **NPE** because you're calling `findViewById(R.id.imgv)` and the `ImageView` is not yet added to your *"activity layout"*, you must call `findViewById` from the *"new inflated"* view otherwise it will return a null object.

muruga5000's answer is right, but the code is little messy. Here is my suggestion:

```
public void onDescriptionClick(){

     RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.camap);

     View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pic_check, mainLayout, false);

     ImageView iv= (ImageView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.imgv);

     iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

     mainLayout.addView(inflatedView);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onDescriptionClick(){

     RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.camap);
     View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pic_check, mainLayout, false);
     RelativeLayout inflatedLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.inflated);
     ImageView iv= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgv);

     mainLayout.addView(inflatedLayout);

     inflatedLayout.addView(iv);

     iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your relative layout and imageview is inside the view
Just do this...

```
     public void onDescriptionClick(){

                    RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.camap);
                    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pic_check, mainLayout, false);
                    RelativeLayout inflatedLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.inflated);
                    ImageView iv= (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgv);mainLayout.addView(inflatedLayout);

                    inflatedLayout.addView(iv);


           iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
mainLayout.addView(inflatedLayout);
}
```